# What are the two extra components delivered with Raspberry Pi 3B+?

Tags: pi-3b+

[image]

Inside the box of my Rapsberry Pi 3B+, I found these two little extra components. The left one looks like a heat sink, the right one resembles the WiFi antenna on the RPi Board.

Is this correct? If so, where would one place the heat sink on the board?

Comment: The heat sink is for the processor, but not needed.

Comment: The heat sink is not *strictly* needed.  But it does help a lot.  Without it your pi will be speed limited by thermal throttling.

Comment: The right one is not a wifi antenna.  Antennas need coax connectors or something similar.